# Error using datastage to connect to informix database

Tags: informix, datastage

when I use datastage to connect to informix database, there comes an error:

main_program: PATH search failure: 
main_program: Error loading "orchinformix": Could not load "orchinformix": libifasf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32.
main_program: Could not locate operator definition, wrapper, or Unix command for "infxread"; please check that all needed libraries are preloaded, and check the PATH for the wrappers

What may cause this problem? Wait for help. Thanks a lot!

[image: error snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error messages is:

> libifasf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32.

You're running a 64-bit system (or, at least, 64-bit executables), but you have a 32-bit version of the Informix ClientSDK or Informix Connect libraries installed, and your `orchinformix` code is trying to load the 32-bit `libifasf.so` library, and failing.

To fix, you need to find out which `libifasf.so` your code is trying to use, and you need to find out whether there's a 64-bit version installed somewhere on the machine.  If there's no 64-bit version, then you'll need to install it, of course.

You then need to adjust things so that the correct library is loaded rather than the incorrect one.  It isn't clear what that'll take.  Look carefully at the configuration and installation instructions.

Normally, `libifasf.so` and other Informix libraries are installed in either `$INFORMIXDIR/lib` or a sub-directory of that (e.g. `$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql` or `$INFORMIXDIR/lib/client`).  You may need to set the INFORMIXDIR environment variable to where the 64-bit software is installed, or you may have to play with other environment variables (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `SHLIB_PATH`, etc), or you may have to tweak a configuration file (`/etc/ld.so.conf` or similar).

If this isn't sufficient help, please identify the platform (o/s and version) that you're using, and also where the Informix database server is running (is it the same machine or a different machine), and the versions of Informix database and connectivity that are in use.  In this context, it is important that 12.10.FC4 and 12.10.UC4 are slightly different; the F indicates 64-bit and the U 32-bit Unix (and W would indicate 32-bit Windows).  Please include all the version number information for the products.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to check the version of Informix ClientSDK?

Comment: Do you know what software is installed?  Did you find `libifasf.so`?  If you find `libifasf.so` in `/opt/ibm/informix/lib/libifasf.so`, then there should be a directory `/opt/ibm/informix/etc` containing a number of `*-cr` files (e.g. `ASF-cr`, `ClientSDK-cr`, …, `IIF-cr`, `OSLIB-cr`). Funnily enough, `ClientSDK-cr` would contain the ClientSDK copyright information; less obviously, `IIF-cr` would contain the information for the server.  You could also run `check_version csdk` or `ifx_getversion clientsdk` from `/opt/ibm/informix/bin`.

Comment: Note that the path name I gave is hypothetical; there is no standard location — or, to the extent there is one, it is `/usr/informix` that holds the `bin`, `etc`, `lib` directories (and some others).  The directory is known by the environment variable used by the software, `$INFORMIXDIR`.  You may need to set `INFORMIXDIR` correctly before the programs run successfully.

Comment: I got a message: Currently installed version: 3.50.FC7.  Does that mean 32bit?

Comment: Interesting…that's a 64-bit version because of the F in the version number — and CSDK 3.50 goes with Informix 11.50 primarily (it'll work with other versions, but it was released at the same time as Informix 11.50).  Are you sure that's the same library as the one that DataStage was using?  What do you get if you run `file /opt/ibm/informix/lib/libifasf.so`?  Does it say '32-bit' or '64-bit' in the output?  Did you have to configure DataStage with a value for INFORMIXDIR?

Comment: The output:  /opt/IBM/informix/lib/libifasf.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped.  And I run: echo $INFORMIXDIR, the output: 
/opt/IBM/informix

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't be getting the error message you showed from the library you showed.  I suppose I might be confused and it is reporting what it wanted instead of what it got — so it wanted a 32-bit library but only found a 64-bit library — but it isn't what I remember happening.  Do you know which executable is generating the error message?  Have you run `file /path/to/executable/generating/error-message`? Does that report 32-bit or 64-bit? Are you sure the message applies to the machine you're looking at? Have you checked to see whether there are any other directories hold `libifasf.so`?

Comment: There is another directory hold that file:
/home/informix/lib/libifasf.so
and that is a 32bit-version file

Comment: And when you run `/home/informix/lib/libifasf.so`, does it report 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it reports 32-bit, we can infer that somehow the software is loading that INFORMIXDIR instead of `/opt/IBM/informix`.  And you will probably have to chase configuration files down to resolve the issue properly.  A quick hack might be: `mv /home/informix /home/informix.32; ln -s /opt/IBM/informix /home/informix` as a suitably privileged (`root`) user.  That leaves a symlink so that `/home/informix/lib/libifasf.so` actually loads the 64-bit library `/opt/IBM/informix/lib/libifasf.so` (for all libraries, etc.)

Comment: You edited your comment while I typed.  The provisional workaround would be interesting, but might break other code that is 32-bit code using `/home/informix` as INFORMIXDIR.  However, it might allow you to verify whether the DataStage stuff can work.  Then you can reinstate the original `/home/informix` (`rm /home/informix; mv /home/informix.32 /home/informix`) and track down the configuration file specifying that DataStage should use `/home/informix` and change it to use `/opt/IBM/informix` instead.  Has your search for other copies of `libifasf.so` been exhaustive?

Comment: I don't have the root privilege. So there are many directories I couldn't search. But I think there are no other copies. And I'm sure there are not other apps using the 32-bit version lib file. I'm asking admin to change $INFORMIXDIR to make a test.